# How can I remove decimal at timer on C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new learner on C#. I try to make a countdown timer on my game. It works just fine but the problem is just a decimal number appear on my timer output. I just want to make timer without a decimal number, can someone help? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
public GameObject game_over;
public Image time_radial;
float time_remaining;
public int max_time = 60;
public Text timeText;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    time_remaining = max_time;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(time_remaining > 0)
    {
        time_remaining -= Time.deltaTime;
        time_radial.fillAmount = time_remaining / max_time;
        timeText.text = time_remaining.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could either use a TimeSpan object or round the `time_remaining` to remove the decimals.

Answer (score 3):

Specify a [format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#numeric-format-specifier-n) to `ToString`:

```
timeText.text = time_remaining.ToString("N0");
```

`N` is the standard numeric format, and `0` specifies that you want 0 digits after the decimal point.

---

Since there was a question about rounding vs. truncating in the comments, the documentation (linked above) states that the value is rounded:

> When precision specifier controls the number of fractional digits in the result string, the result string reflects a number that is rounded to a representable result nearest to the infinitely precise result. If there are two equally near representable results:
>
> - On .NET Framework and .NET Core up to .NET Core 2.0, the runtime selects the result with the greater least significant digit (that is, using MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).
> - On .NET Core 2.1 and later, the runtime selects the result with an even least significant digit (that is, using MidpointRounding.ToEven).

Answer (score -1):

[Math.Round()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_) is what your looking for.

Comment: No it's not ... the issue is only in the string output not the actual value ...